# Allocating just one more variable inside a function greatly increases execution time

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-management, cygwin

I've run into some strange behavior of my program. I have a function that gets called a lot during the execution, and when i declare just one more `double` variable inside this function, the program runs 10 times slower. Here's the function code:

```
    void MazeWall::goSomewhere( WallInfo &caller )
    {   
        double slowDown = 0;

        bool possibleWays[numberOfDirections];    
        bool BadWays[numberOfDirections];
        int weightsOfDirections[numberOfDirections] = {};   
        int numOfPosWays = findPosWays( caller, possibleWays );
        int numOfBadWays = findBadWays( caller, BadWays, possibleWays );
        int selectedDir;

        if ( numOfPosWays == numOfBadWays ) // if all ways are bad
        {
            selectedDir = randomChoice( BadWays, numberOfDirections, true ); // select a bad way
        }
        else
        {
            for ( int k = 0; k < numberOfDirections; k++ )
            {
                possibleWays[k] = possibleWays[k] && (!BadWays[k] ); // leave only good ways
            }
            int step = 32 / numberOfDirections;

            // check how occupied these ways are:
            for ( int l = 0; l < numberOfDirections; ++l )
            {
                CyclicInt directionOfSight( 0, 31, 28 );

                if ( possibleWays[l] )
                {
                    directionOfSight = directionOfSight + l*step;
                    int integralDistance = 0;
                    for ( int m = 0; m <= 8; ++m )
                    {
                        integralDistance += caller.distanceToAWall32( directionOfSight, 32 );
                        directionOfSight = directionOfSight + 1;
                    }
                    weightsOfDirections[l] = integralDistance;

                }
            }
            selectedDir = weightedRandom( weightsOfDirections, numberOfDirections );
        }
        CyclicInt cyclicDir( 0, numberOfDirections - 1, selectedDir );

        caller.step( cyclicDir ); // make 1 step in selected direction
    }
```

In this code, there is a variable called `slowDown` that causes problems. If i comment it out, the program runs fast. If i don't initialize it to a specific value, program also runs fast. But if i leave the code like this it runs almost 10 times slower. I do not use this variable anywhere in the program.

Also, i have found out that once i added one `double` variable, adding another 35 `doubles` does not affect performance, but adding 36th one causes another drop of speed, so it can't be simply because of allocation overhead.

I always use the same input conditions to test my program. I used a global variable to find out how many times this function gets called - about 3000+ times for the specific test conditions.

I tried this with other functions, for example, `findPosWays()` and `findBadWays()`, it worked for some and did not worked for others.

I am using cygwin g++ compiler on windows 7.

My question is, why is this happening and how can i avoid this behavior. I guess there are some blocks of memory inside which functions should fit, and if they don't, it causes some very expensive operation of finding a bigger block. But if so, shouldn't it be done during compilation, not at runtime?

I am worrying that there might be more functions in my code that have "wrong" size and can slow down the program, so it seems important to detect such functions.

Update:
I've been asked to paste assembler code for fast and slow versions of the program, so here it is:
http://pastebin.com/At0Sy0ZT - slow version

http://pastebin.com/qdY8G7C5 - fast version

Don't know if this would be of any help, even though i placed `goSomewhere()` into a separate file, the assembler code is still quite long.

Comment: I guess its due to padding, take a look at the compiled asm code

Comment: I'd wager your cache misses more when that variable is defined.

Comment: If you compile with warnings turned on then you will get a warning for unused variables. An unused variable is basically a logic error in my opinion, so complaining that it runs slow is a secondary problem.

Comment: paste assembly output from both versions - slow and fast

Comment: To @Paranaix - I don't know how to read assembler code, i am only learning c++ for several months. Where can i find the assembler code of my program?

Comment: I added -O2 flag for optimization, but it made it even slower. Also i turned on warnings as @Brandin said, and got a bunch of them. I will try to fix them and see what happens.

Comment: @spiderface adding -O2 slowed down execution?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes, it did, a lot. The fastest version takes about 400 ms, the slow version (with `double slowDown = 0`) - 3 seconds, and the slowest version (with `slowDown` and -O2) - about 10 seconds.

Comment: @spiderface Is your code available somewhere (for example github)? It's hard to tell what is going on without seeing the rest of the code. I have a bunch of guesses but seeing the code would help a lot.

Comment: @Ali No it's not available right now, but i will upload it since you asked. But first i'll deal with some warnings that i am getting. The program is basically a 2d maze generator that makes random mazes as char** arrays and finds a way from entrance to exit.

Comment: @spiderface Please fix the warnings and make the code available to us. We can only guess without the code.

Comment: @spiderface -O2 should only be expected to any good on correct code. In what way is declaring a variable which is never used considered necessary and correct? If you actually need that variable, then you'd be willing to pay for it. If you don't, then it's your job to get rid of it, it's not the optimizers job to do that.

Comment: @Brandin I can easily get rid of that variable, i just want to know how can one little variable mess up the code so badly.

Comment: @spiderface Well think of it this way, your task is writing code for the optimizer, you can either a) invest your time in optimizing cases which actually occur or b) invest your time in optimizing cases which are already covered by warnings (such as `-Wunused-variable`). Why on earth would you choose b) when this is a waste of developer time

Comment: @Brandin One reason to do so is that i may run into this problem later, when i will actually need that problematic variable. So it is better to figure out right now what is wrong. Do you think the variable causes performance problems only because it is unused?

Comment: @spiderface If you might need it later but not right now then comment it out or use `#ifdef` or something to programmatically remove it from compilation. Exccept in rare circumstances, unused variables are a logic error. If you actually need them, then obviously you have to pay something for them (e.g. 4-8 bytes for primitive types and some kind of instruction every time it is initialized).

Comment: @Brandin I will never need this exact variable in this exact function, so i can just remove it completely, but then i will never know why exactly it causes such a problem.

Comment: @Brandin the investigation, and the question, are good if they are actually valid.

Answer (score 4):

Your mistake is that you're not compiling with optimizations on, or your compiler is outdated. An unused variable will be stripped out of the executable completely by any decent compiler.

We can speculate on alignment of `possibleWays` and `BadWays` in memory based on the extra variable, more cache misses, etc., but the point is any profiling done without optimizations is void of any meaning.

Answer (score 3):

It might be useful to look at the intermediary assembler code in both cases. Adding one more variable **might** alter how the compiler utilises CPU registers vs stack-allocated variables. The former are obviously faster.

Answer (score 0):

I found a dumb error that slowed down the code. I was instantiating an object of a class using that very object name as an argument, like this

```
MyClass obj( obj );
```

I don't know why this worked at all, but it was the reason why my program was slow. I guess allocations of new variables caused some shifts in memory that resulted in random slow downs and speed ups.